# What does `come of age` mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> This two-step strategy has its roots as far back as Aristotle who used
>       Greek letters as symbols in presenting syllogisms. But the strategy **came of
>       age** in the nineteenth century with the German logician Gottlob Frege

It seems to mean either that its age came in the ninteenth century or that the strategy originates from the ninteenth century.

Which one is it?

Comment: This is an idiom. *[come of age](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/come-of-age): 1.1 (Of a movement or activity) become fully established.* (ODO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've clipped the phrase prematurely. The full idiom is *come of age*.

Here is the meaning of the idiom, *to come of age*:

> To reach maturity.

Example:

> After years of sophisticated mimicry, Japanese design has *come of age*.

([American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+of+age))

Comment: The idiom is based on the concept of a person "coming of age" -- reaching an age where they intellectually, legally, and socially can participate in society as an adult.